# Adding a dynamic row in a table in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to add a row when I click on Add button, the table exists in a Reactive form.

[image: Here's the structure that I'm talking about]

Here's how I tried `html file`

```
<tr *ngFor='let row of tableRows'>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
        <td fxFlex="22">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Product </mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="tableRows.productId" required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor='let product of productList' [value]="product.productId">
                        {{product.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td fxFlex="15">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Price </mat-label>
                <input type='number' matInput [(ngModel)]="tableRows.price" name="" id="" placeholder="Price" required>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td fxFlex="15">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Loan Term </mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="tableRows.loanTermId" required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor='let loanTerm of loanTermList' [value]="loanTerm.loanTermId">
                        {{loanTerm.numberOfMonths}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td fxFlex="15">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Quantity </mat-label>
                <input type='number' matInput [(ngModel)]="tableRows.quantity" name="" id="" placeholder="Quantity" required>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td fxFlex="15">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Deposit </mat-label>
                <input type='number' matInput [(ngModel)]="tableRows.deposit" name="" id="" placeholder="Deposit" required>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td fxFlex="15">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Total </mat-label>
                <input type='number' matInput [(ngModel)]="tableRows.total" name="" id="" placeholder="Total" required>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
```

and here's how I'm trying in `ts` file

```
newRow = { productId: '', price: '', loanTermId: '', quantity: '', deposit: '', total: '' };
tableRows = [{ productId: '', price: '', loanTermId: '', quantity: '', deposit: '', total: '' }];

  addTableRow() {
    this.newRow = { productId: '', price: '', loanTermId: '', quantity: '', deposit: '', total: '' };
    this.tableRows.push(this.newRow)
  }
```

Hoping that I'd work.
I receive the following error in console

```
ERROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.
```

Comment: if you use reactive forms you can use formarray. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: thanks, but how do I achieve the functionality of adding a row on click event ?

Comment: Angular is creating a FormGroup instance for you since you are probably using the form element somewhere in your template, and using ngModel directive defeats the purpose of the FormGroup system. If what you want is to get rid of the error without changing your implementation, try adding `ngNoForm` to your form element, as in `<form ngNoForm> ...`, but I strongly recommend you to have a look at angular's formGroup, formArray and formControls, they really help in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use ngModel with FormControl. Instead Use FormControlName and FormArray.
In component,ts file

```
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

In constructor:: `constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }`

```
    ngOnInit() {

    /* Initiate the form structure */
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      pData: this._fb.array([])
    })
    this.addFormDetails();
  }

   addFormDetails {
     this.rowDataArray.push(this.BuildFormDynamic(data_from_backend));
   }

    get formData() { // use getter method to get the row array
       return this.productForm.get('pData') as FormArray;
  }
```

Access data_from_backend and assign it here, if black then no data will show in HTML, if have value then values will be displayed on HTML

```
    BuildFormDynamic(data_from_backend): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      abc: [data_from_backend.abc],
      def: [data_from_backend.def],
      ghi: [data_from_backend.ghi],
      jkl: [data_from_backend.jkl],
      mno: [data_from_backend.mno],
      pqr: [data_from_backend.pqr]
    });
  }
```

In HTML, access these valiable using FOrmControlName
Name your form element`productForm: FormGroup;` Same form name should be given in html file like this::

```
    `<form [formGroup]="productForm">
      <div formArrayName="pData">
    <div *ngFor="let item of formData.controls; let pointIndex=index" [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
    <label>
      Test Name: <input formControlName="abc" />
    </label>
<button type="button" (click)="deleteFormRows(pointIndex)">Delete Selling Point</button>
    </div>
<button type="button" (click)="addFormRows()">Add Selling Point</button>
  </div>
    </form>`
```

To add and Delete rows

```
 addFormRows() {
    this.formData.push(this.fb.group({point:''}));
  }
deleteFormRows(index) {
    this.formData.removeAt(index);
  }
```

This is just an example, customise it according to your requirement. Lemme know if any issues

Comment: I read the angular guide of reactive forms with the similar example as of mine, but the problem is that in guide they were only using a single input, where as I've a complete table. that's why I'm stuck

Comment: I have made some edit to add as many as data is required in formControlArray